# VMWare Workstation 7.1.2 keeps hanging

Tags: vmware-workstation

I am using VMWare Workstation 7.1.2, on a windows 7 x64 installation, 8gb ram, 2.8 GHz quad core processor.  I have supplied the VM with sufficient processor & ram useage (all 4 processors + 4gb Ram).

My issue is that, on a regular basis, VMWare hangs for about 10-15s at a time, showing a prompt, "VMware is not responding, close application or wait for application".  I can be working away for a time on the VM and it just hangs every few minutes.  I have monitored the overall PC's resources and nothing seems to be going beyond the PC's capabilities.

Is anyone able to assist with this please, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Version 7 hasn't been out for 12 months yet so presumably you have a valid support contract with VMWare - have you thought of placing a call with them?